# Typescript Union type & Not assignable error

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors, union-types

I'm not sure why this isn't working. If Term can be both Node and Literal, and I'm providing a Node. Why is that not accepted as Term in here? How can I best solve this?

Note that the interfaces and union type come from a different library, so I can only change the `NamedNode` class definition

Click [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDk4FsIBN0D2uKA3gLABQyyAbnADYCuEAXMgM5hSgDmA3JWoQAjowbsAFJChYWAFWhYAlCwBGBAvQhwQAigF9KoafCRoAMsGkNk5KrQbM2nbiH6Dk9HTzE9WHLl49IVFxKUV5RRV1TW1dSkMKMABPAAcUBRlkAF40TBx8IhQAHwsraAY9OFUXRDBkBC92dmQAITh2CEJiSjtqagQCEBdGBDACKAlUxlV6YAQHJghsgHIVpRJExMaOlvy8bpQIAA9IEFwW9s7D5GAsVK0ccBaMbAOi2w9B4a5R8cm6EtVus+v12Ix0gDHBAlMFkIkPCIxPRJNJZJllGoNFodJ97NQoBAwIwoCBkGictlcmAABbAdhwhH2EBFACC7AACnAoG9pBJAU42h0ukUNpQAJDiwnE0nkunsAB0SLCAphenFWyAA) for this code in typescript playground

```
interface INamedNode {
  value: string;
  equals(term:Term):boolean;
}
interface ILiteral {
  value: string;
  language: string;
  equals(term:Term):boolean;
}
type Term = INamedNode | ILiteral;
abstract class BaseNode
{
    constructor(public value=''){}
}
class NamedNode extends BaseNode implements INamedNode {
  constructor(value=''){
    super(value);
  }

  equals(term:Term):boolean {
    return term === this;
  }

  nodeAsParameter(value: BaseNode){
        return this.equals(value);
    }
}
```

Current error

> Argument of type 'BaseNode' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Term'.
> Type 'BaseNode' is missing the following properties from type 'ILiteral': value, language, equals

Comment: The problem actually is we are invoking `equals(term: Term): boolean;`, but passing it a type `Node`. We should be passing it a value of type `Term`(at least).

Comment: @NalinRanjan but that trickles down to other methods and then my whole code becomes full of the much more generic `Term` instead of the more specific `Node`

Answer (score 0):

How about this....

```typescript
interface INamedNode extends Node {
  value: string;
  equals(term: Term): boolean;
}
interface ILiteral {
  value: string;
  language: string;
  equals(term: Term): boolean;
}

type Term = INamedNode | ILiteral;

abstract class BaseNode extends HTMLElement {
  constructor(public value = '') {
    super();
  }

  equals(term: Term): boolean {
    return term === this;
  }
}

class NamedNode extends BaseNode implements INamedNode {
  constructor(value = '') {
    super(value);
  }

  nodeAsParameter(value: BaseNode) {
    return this.equals(value);
  }
}
```

We can also very well work with `Node` alone, without having to have a separate `BaseNode` defined.